# Disable/Enable Button Through Input Conditions [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I am developing an app in AngularJS.

**1.** I would like to know how can I disable a button if the input value typed by the user is not a item of the `uib-typeahead` list (in this case the Array `items`)? And enable it when it is a item of the array?

**2.** And also, how can I disable the same button when the user tries to add a item of the Array `items` through the Add button that was already added? The items are saved in the Array `addedItems`.

This is the input and button in HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search1" uib-typeahead="item for item in items 
    | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"/>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="action()" 
ng-disabled="(!search1)">Add</button>
```

This is a sample of the `items` Array structure:

```
var items = ["admin1", "admin2", "admin3", "admin4", "admin5"];
```

The `action()` function is defined in the controller in JavaScript:

```
$scope.items = ["admin1", "admin2", "admin3", "admin4", "admin5"];
$scope.search1 = undefined;
$scope.addedItems = [];
$scope.action = function() {
  $scope.addedItems.push($scope.search1);
  }
```

Thank you *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I can completely understand what do you want do. Let me try.

```
$scope.items = ["admin1", "admin2", "admin3", "admin4", "admin5"];
$scope.search1 = undefined;
$scope.addedItems = [];

//this method will help you know if the item exists already in the list
$scope.exists = function(list, item){
    return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
}

$scope.action = function() {
    $scope.addedItems.push($scope.search1);
}
```

After you can use the method to enable or disable the button like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="action()" 
ng-disabled="exists(addedItems, search1)">Add</button>
```

I hope this may help you!

Comment: Thank you * This solved Problem #2. Do you know how to solve Problem #1? (1. I would like to know how can I disable a button if the input value typed by the user is not a item of the uib-typeahead list (in this case the Array items)? And enable it when it is a item of the array?)

Comment: Meanwhile, I did something similar to solve my Problem #2 with a new method "itemList()". HTML Button now with "ng-disabled="exists(addedItems, search1) || itemList(search1, items)""

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I would like to know how can I disable a button if the input value typed by the user is not a item of the uib-typeahead list (in this
>      case the Array items)? And enable it when it is a item of the array?

In your case [ui-select](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/) will fit your need.

> 2. And also, how can I disable the same button when the user tries to add a item of the Array items through the Add button that was already
>      added? The items are saved in the Array addedItems.

There are couple ways of doing it. 
1. Add a `ng-change` method to your input and inside the method do your unique check. Then bind the unique check result to the `ng-disabled` in the button. 
2. This will be reusable but bit more complicated. Have a custom unique check directive that takes a list and an input. And have the button listen to the error. Something like `ng-disabled="form.search1.$unique"`

Comment: How "ui-select" can solve my Problem #1? (Problem #2 is already solved)

Comment: Since `'ui-select' will only allow item from the list, you don't need to disable the button.